# Geofencing and push notification for cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, push-notification, geofencing

I've been working on this for last few days and am unable to get a proper implementation idea. I have a cordova android app in which I need the following -

1. Send a push notification to the mobile based on a set of defined geofences.

For the Geofences, I thought I can use Cordova Geolocation's WatchPosition method. Using this, whenever there is a change in position and when that position matches my Geofence, the mobile should receive a push notification. I understand that using Watchposition I can get latitude and longitude values but how to check the geofence's radius???

For push notifications I have a cordova plugin [here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/tree/2de525365bcc2391ad8d0a399ef4662e83ac0474)

I need to know how to integrate this push notification to a geofence using watchPosition in Cordova.
Or kindly let me know is there any other way to implement this.

I checked something in [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138380/push-notifications-to-gcm-with-geofencing-parameters) but there is no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) with this you should be able to get the distance between the two points.

There is an implementation of the functions written for Phonegap in this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17031284/147323

Answer (score 0):

Check out OneSignal.com and https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence
It allows you to do just that, what im doing is based on the Transition to automatically enter a user in a segment when they enter that geozone and remove them when they exit. OneSignal has beaucoup API reference to make this super easy. Good Luck